# Find $F'(x)$ where $F(x) = \int_1^{3x} y^{-1}e^{xy} dy$

Tags: calculus

Find $F'(x)$ where $F(x) = \int_1^{3x} y^{-1}e^{xy} dy$.

I just took the derivative with respect to x as:

$F'(x) = \int_1^{3x}e^{xy} \,dy$ which should be equal to $e^{3x^{2}} -e^x\over x$.

However my textbook made the calculation as:

$F'(x) = 3x^{-1} e^{3x^{2}} 3+\int_1^{3x}e^{xy} \,dy$ which equals to $2e^{3x^{2}} -e^x\over x$

I don't understand why it is like that there was a theorem such as $\partial F\over\partial x_j$ = $\int$...$\int$$\partial f(x,y)\over\partial x_j$$d^ny$ where $F(x)$ is defined by

$F(x) = \int$...$\int$ $f(x,y) d^ny$ I just wanted to use that what am I mising?

Comment: When you state the theorem you used, it implicitly assumes that the limits are independent of $x$. In this case, they are dependent on $x$, which will affect the answer. You can refer to the Leibniz Theorem for more details.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: make a change of variable $u=xy$, then differentiate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use that theorem. You can make the change of variable $t=xy$, then $\frac{dt}{dy} = x, \frac{dt}{x} = dy$. With this in mind, you can rewrite your integral as:

$$\int _ 1 ^{3x} \frac{e^{xy}}{y} dy = \int_x^{3x^2} \frac{e^t}{t/x} \frac{dt}{x} = \int _x ^{3x^2} \frac{e^t}{t}dt = F(x).$$

Finding $F'(x)$ from here is straightforward: $$F'(x) = \frac{e^{3x^2}}{3x^2} (6x) - \frac{e^x}{x}(1) = \frac{2e^{3x^2}-e^x}{x}.$$

Comment: may I ask how did you find $F'(x)$ ?

Comment: If you have $F(x) = \int _a^b f(t) dt$ then $F'(x) = b'f(b)- a'f(a)$